# run telegram in a docker

Tags: docker, telegram, xserver

I want to run telegram in docker, so I found this repository: https://hub.docker.com/r/xorilog/telegram/
I tried to run this command:

```
docker run --rm -it --name telegram \
       --hostname=$(hostname) \
       -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
       -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native \
       -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
       -v "/home/$(whoami)/.Xauthority:/home/user/.Xauthority" \
       -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse \
       -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
       -v /home/legion/Documents/docker/:/home/user/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/ \
       xorilog/telegram
```

but failed.
And the terminal errors show:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: unable to load driver: i915_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

My computer system is Ubuntu 21.04, and docker version is Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636.
I have googled these errors, but nothing can help me.

Comment: Telegram-for-desktop uses Qt, which uses OpenGL for rendering. So you need to set-up OpenGL for Docker, which is hard.

Comment: But the initial fatal error message is straightforward: it doesn't have permission to write to your local desktop folder.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, that's it, but after I set 777 to that directory, another question appears, please help